# Is this JavaScript encoding properly written?

Tags: javascript

I have tried some tips I was given on regards URL encoding but I have no success so far. First, I was given this format,

```
var url = "http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/add?title=" 
      + encodeURIComponent(%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%) 
      + "&url=" + encodeURIComponent("http://lilaboutique.co.uk/products/" 
          + encodeURIComponent(%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%) 
          + "&imgurl=" + encodeURIComponent(%%GLOBAL_ThumbImageURL%%) 
          + "&desc=" + encodeURIComponent(%%GLOBAL_ProductDesc%%) 
          + "&price=" + encodeURIComponent(%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%));
```

which never got to be passed to the href dunno for what reason. Then I played with it some more,

```
var url = "http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/add?title=encodeURIComponent(%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%)&url=http://lilaboutique.co.uk/products/encodeURIComponent(%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%)&imgurl=encodeURIComponent(%%GLOBAL_ThumbImageURL%%)&desc=encodeURIComponent(%%GLOBAL_ProductDesc%%)&price=encodeURIComponent(%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%)";
```

this time the URL was passed but the values were mixed between the appropriate and other fields displaying the encoding function itself.

Any help clarifying my mistakes is greatly appreciated. I would like to encode just price and description, seems to be the fields giving problems.

A regular link does render without problems

```
var url = "www.google.com";

var myAnchor = document.getElementById('myAnchor');

myAnchor.href = url;
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nicer, cleaner way of doing this:

```
var toEncode = {
  title:    '%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%',
  url:      'http://lilaboutique.co.uk/products/%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%',
  imgurl:   '%%GLOBAL_ThumbImageURL%%',
  desc:     '%%GLOBAL_ProductDesc%%',
  price:    '%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%'
};

var index, queryString = '';

for (index in toEncode)
{
  queryString += index + '=' + encodeURIComponent(toEncode[index]) + '&';
}

var url = "http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/add?" + queryString;
```

Comment: Actually, that closing bracket is at the end.  It's my fault for formatting his code incorrectly, the last 4 lines should have been indented further to clarify.

Comment: that piece of code is artwork haha , but have to say that I still getting the problems from the beginning. I don't know for what reason price and description are not being passed. I wish i had access to the php script files, that would be a breeze but bigcommerce does not provide for that. If you have other tips to get deeper into what those global variables are returning, please let me know. Thanks for the help.

Comment: just do some debugging `for (i in toEncode) alert(i+'='+toEncode[i]);` and see what each is returning

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `$.param(obj)` is [very nice](http://jsfiddle.net/ADqK6/).

In general though I would take a similar approach if you wanted to roll your own.  Make a function that accepts an Object, and returns a query string.  Then in your server template, you have:

```
var urlData = {
  url: "http://lilaboutique.co.uk/products/",
  imgurl: "%%GLOBAL_ThumbImageURL%%",
  desc: "%%GLOBAL_ProductDesc%%"
  // etc...
}

var url = "http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/add?" + $.param(urlData);
```

Or whatever conversion function you want to use.